# Publisher only publishing two of my three variables

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been playing around with publishers and subscribers, challenging myself with modification on the tutorial pub/sub examples just to gain a foundation.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "project_one_publisher"); //publisher node name
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher p_one_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("project_one", 1);

    std_msgs::Float64 tens;
    std_msgs::Float64 hundreds;
    std_msgs::Float64 thousands;

    ros::Rate naptime(1.0);

    tens.data=0.0;
    hundreds.data=0.0;
    thousands.data=0.0;

    while (ros::ok())

{
     p_one_pub.publish(tens);
     tens.data=tens.data + 10;
     p_one_pub.publish(hundreds);
     hundreds.data=hundreds.data + 100;
     p_one_pub.publish(thousands);
     thousands.data=thousands.data + 1000;

     naptime.sleep();
    }
}
```

I have no problems running my code however when I use rostopic echo  it only prints the hundreds and thousands value, it doesn't display the tens value.

I also created a subscriber to subscribe to incoming data however that only reads the thousands value while randomly reading the hundreds value, ex:

```
[ INFO] [1579646242.765639960]: recieved value is: 264000.000000
[ INFO] [1579646243.804282174]: recieved value is: 265000.000000
[ INFO] [1579646244.774907455]: recieved value is: 266000.000000
[ INFO] [1579646245.809710083]: recieved value is: 2670.000000
[ INFO] [1579646245.809943092]: recieved value is: 267000.000000
[ INFO] [1579646246.763998267]: recieved value is: 268000.000000
[ INFO] [1579646247.766197402]: recieved value is: 269000.000000
```

So ya, my question is why on the echo topic, it's only showing the hundreds and thousands value but not the tens value and on the subscriber side, why it's mostly using the thousands value.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342229/publisher-only-publishing-two-of-my-three-variables/) by [ZuberA](https://answers.ros.org/users/51127/zubera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My best guess is that this error is caused by you setting the `queue_size` to 1. Even though you are sleeping for a full second, you are trying to publish very quickly (three messages right in a row). If you setup your publisher to have a bit more of a queue, it will have time to publish all messages in the queue before trying to publish again on the next loop.

Read more here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZuberA](https://answers.ros.org/users/51127/zubera/) on 2020-01-21**:
That did the trick! I had to match the queue size on the subscriber too and got it to read properly, thank you!